# How to Advance void * pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, casting, void-pointers

In C++ I had:

```
MallocMetadata *tmp = static_cast<MallocMetadata *> (p);
```

But now I want tmp to be 5 bytes before in memory so I tried:

```
MallocMetadata *tmp = static_cast<MallocMetadata *> (p-5);
```

But that didn't compile, I read some articles which suggested this (and didn't work too):

```
MallocMetadata *tmp = static_cast<MallocMetadata *> (static_cast<char *> (p) - 5);
```

How to fix this problem, please note: I am sure that place in memory is legal plus I want tmp to be of type MallocMetadata* to use it later.

Comment: If you're trying to figure this out, why are you trying to do everything in a single line of code?  Break up the code first, see what works with 2 or 3 lines, then condense it to a single line given what works.  Also, with multiple lines, you have a better chance to determine any point of failure (and given the code, that is quite possible).

Comment: FWIW, creating a `MallocMetadata *` that doesn't actually point to a `MallocMetadata` is a recipe for disaster.  You'll need to be very careful as this is shot yourself in the foot territory.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have mentioned it's guarded :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie for optimization

Comment: @pow -- The compiler will optimize the code.  Second, your first goal is to get the program working, no?  If it's not working, what's there to "optimize"?  You can't optimize non-working code.

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) please explain what this code should do (what is business logic/value). Drop thinking how to fix your solution. Your solution is strange and defensively invalid - most probably impossible to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C++ How to Advance void * pointer?

It is not possible to advance a `void*`.

Advancing a pointer by one modifies the pointer to point to the next sibling of the previously pointed object within an array of objects. The distance between two elements of an array differs between objects of different types. The distance is exactly the same as the size of the object.

Thus to advance a pointer, it is necessary to know the size of the pointed object. `void*` can point to an object of any size, and there is no way to get information about that size from the pointer.

What you can do instead is static cast `void*` to the dynamic type of the pointed object. The size of the pointed object is then known by virtue of knowing the type of the pointer, as long as the type is complete. You can then use pointer arithmetic to advance the converted pointer to a sibling of the pointed object.

> But now I want tmp to be 5 bytes before in memory

Before we proceed any further, I want to make it clear that this is an unsafe thing to attempt, and you must know the language rules in detail to have even a remote chance of doing this correctly. I urge you to consider whether doing this is necessary.

To get a pointer to the memory address 5 bytes before, you can static_cast `void*` to `unsigned char*` and do pointer arithmetic on the converted pointer:

```
static_cast<unsigned char*>(p) - 5
```

---

> ```
> MallocMetadata *tmp = static_cast<MallocMetadata *> (static_cast<char *> (p) - 5);
> ```

`char*` isn't static-castable to arbitrary object pointer types. **if** the memory address is properly aligned **and** ((the address contains an object of similar type) or (`MallocMetadata` is a trivial type and the address doesn't contain an object of another type and you're going to write to the address and not read, thereby creating a new object)), then you can use reinterpret_cast instead:

```
MallocMetadata *tmp = reinterpret_cast<MallocMetadata*>(
    static_cast<char*>(p) - 5
);
```

A full example:

```
// preparation
int offset = 5;
std::size_t padding = sizeof(MallocMetadata) >= offset
    ? 0
    : sizeof(MallocMetadata) - offset;
auto align = static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(MallocMetadata));
void* p_storage = ::operator new(sizeof(MallocMetadata) + padding, align);
MallocMetadata* p_mm = new (p_storage) MallocMetadata{};
void* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p_mm) + offset;

// same as above
MallocMetadata *tmp = reinterpret_cast<MallocMetadata*>(
    static_cast<char*>(p) - offset
);

// cleanup
tmp->~MallocMetadata();
::operator delete(tmp);
```

Comment: Technically, a `void*` can only point to an object of type `void`. The size of an object of type `void` is undefined. Any attempt to advance a pointer by an undefined value is also undefined. It's simply an undefined operation.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb Objects of type `void` cannot be created, thus `void*` cannot point to such object.

Comment: The only thing you can do with a `void*` is pass pointers to other objects through it, which means casting a pointer to some other type of object and then casting it back to the original pointer type. Anything else is undefined, including casting to a pointer to a different type than the original object. Undefined. It might work. It might not. It might invoke nasal monkeys.

Advancing a `void*` is undefined, because the size of an object of type `void` is undefined.  Plain and simple. Casting through void to alias types is undefined. Plain and simple.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb To be more specific, advancing a `void*` is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to convert pointers other than `void*` to another pointers.

```
MallocMetadata *tmp = reinterpret_cast<MallocMetadata *> (static_cast<char *> (p) - 5);
```

Another choice is casting the `char*` after subtracting something to `void*` again.

```
MallocMetadata *tmp = static_cast<MallocMetadata *> (static_cast<void *> (static_cast<char *> (p) - 5));
```

Comment: Sorry but why we need this at all. I never heard of this and prefer not to use reinterpret_cast

Comment: @pow Another choice added.

Comment: @pow you attempt to convert a pointer to `char` to a completely unrelated pointer type. This is a dangerous operation, which can be done with a `reinterpret_cast`. Quoting Straustrup: " reinterpret_cast<int>(p) is an ugly notation for an ugly operation".

Comment: @pow Why do you prefer not to use reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @eerorika it's not safe

Comment: @pow What you're tring to do is unsafe. You can only do it with `reinterpret_cast` because that is the tool for this unsafe thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you'll make of this, but I'll try:

There's a requirement in the standard that `void *` and character pointers have the same representation and alignment that falls out of C and how historically you had character pointer types where you now have `void *`.

If you have a `void *`, actually a `void *` and not some other type of pointer, and you wanted to advance it a byte at a time, you should be able to create a reference-to-pointer-to-unsigned-character bound to the pointer-to-void, as in:

```cpp
auto &ucp = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *&>(void_pointer);
```

And now it should be possible to manipulate `void_pointer` through operations on `ucp` reference.

So `++ucp` will advance it, and therefore `void_pointer`, by one.